# Mysql Query Help to compare multiple urls

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db with 14k links, im trying to find each url that is in the db twice or more.

Using this query below I'am able to strip them down to simple url's.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3) FROM Links WHERE url REGEXP '^[^:]+://';
```

I'm looking for help in now taking the results and counting them to present a list of all the domains that have 2 or more entries in my DB:

Comment: `... GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',3) HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`

Comment: Thank You.... It works just as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Once you strip down all the URLs to their simple form you can use the following query to find the no. of counts of the URLs appearing in the db.

```
SELECT *
FROM `Links`
GROUP BY url(`url`)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```